# Extracting data from a text field with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a pandas dataframe by extracting information from notes. I would like to get a few columns

```
phonenumber    | status   | result      | notation
(999) 555-9898  Partial    Generic VM   VOICE MAIL LEFT
```

Notes:

```
Event   Notation
Call    Call to (Home) (999) 555-9898 ended. Partial – Generic VM --> - VOICE MAIL LEFT 
Call    Call to (Work) (999) 555-9898 ended. Partial - Voice Mail, No Message left -->
Call    Call to (Work) (999) 555-9898 ended. Positive –  Spoke to Receptionist --> 
Call    Call to (Mobile) (999) 555-9898 ended. Partial – Generic VM --> - Unable to reach customer, voice message left and text sent
Procedure   Procedure 'Verify' is checked
Procedure   Procedure 'Duplicate Check' is checked
Procedure   Procedure 'Check Something' is checked
Procedure   Procedure 'Scenario' is checked
Procedure   Procedure 'Attempt' is checked
```

I would make a second dataframe and I would try to pull the single word in the single quotes for the Procedure event.

```
procedure
Verify
Duplicate Check
Check Something
```

Comment: The focus of this question is a bit off. The challenging part here is extracting the data fields from text following some non-typical pattern. Pandas is of little help for this purpose. Storing the results in a DataFrame or even just a list of dicts afterwards is very straightforward compared to that.

Comment: I suggest you read http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html

Comment: Yep, Valgur is right. That should be possible using regular expressions

Answer (score 2):

To give you an idea, here might be something to start with (However, be aware that it is my first time using regular expressions):

```
import re
data = []
with open('notes.txt', 'r') as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        data.append(line.strip('\n'))
data
```

`['Call    Call to (Home) (999) 555-9898 ended. Partial – Generic VM --> - VOICE MAIL LEFT ',
 'Call    Call to (Work) (999) 555-9898 ended. Partial - Voice Mail, No Message left -->',
 'Call    Call to (Work) (999) 555-9898 ended. Positive –  Spoke to Receptionist --> ',
 'Call    Call to (Mobile) (999) 555-9898 ended. Partial – Generic VM --> - Unable to reach customer, voice message left and text sent',
 "Procedure   Procedure 'Verify' is checked",
 "Procedure   Procedure 'Duplicate Check' is checked",
 "Procedure   Procedure 'Check Something' is checked",
 "Procedure   Procedure 'Scenario' is checked",
 "Procedure   Procedure 'Attempt' is checked"]`

```
phone = []
status = []
for line in data:
    tmp = line.split(' ')
    if tmp[0] == 'Call':
        p_phone = re.compile('[(]\d{3}[)] \d{3}-\d{4}')
        p_status = re.compile('Partial|Positive')
        phone.append(p_phone.findall(line))
        status.append(p_status.findall(line))
    elif tmp[0] == "Procedure":
        pass
print(phone)
print(status)
```

`[['(999) 555-9898'], ['(999) 555-9898'], ['(999) 555-9898'], ['(999) 555-9898']]
[['Partial'], ['Partial'], ['Positive'], ['Partial']]`